# Key Java JML proover passes this algorithm that reads a specific array element which triggers a NullPointerException? it should fail instead

Tags: java, formal-verification, jml, openjml, key-formal-verification

I'm tyring to better understand the limits of the Key proover for Java.
I have come up with a scenario where a specific array element will trigger a null pointer exception.
When I run this through the proover it passes. Any idea why this is? It should fail as the null pointer will be thrown at array element 86454.
Please note "normal_behaviour" means that it should terminate without exceptions.

```
/*@ 
 @ normal_behaviour
 @ requires true;
 @ ensures \result == 7;
 @*/ 
public static int tmp() {
    Object[] arr = new Object[999999];
    arr[86454] = new Integer(6);
    for (int i=0;i<999999;i++){
        if (arr[i]!=null && arr[i].equals(new Integer(6))){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
    return 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your specification only covers the normal behaviour, and not the exceptional case.

Normal behaviour means, that all post-condition have to be adhered, after the method is executed. Therefore, there exists a return value, and you are allowed to access it (`\result`). For the exceptional case, your `requires` clause would not be well-defined.

If you want to the specify the case, when an exception occurs you should use `exceptional_behavior` and in the case you want to show the "exception-freeness"
use `behavior`. Both in conjunction with a `signals` clause. For example, use the following to show the exception-freeness:

```
/*@ public behavior 
    requires true; 
    signals (Exception e) false;
*/
```

This contract can not fulfilled by a method, which could throw an exception.

Please refer to [Chapter 7](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Eahrendt/papers/JML16chapter.pdf) (especially "7.3.3 Semantics of Normal Behavior Specification Cases") of the key book.

Comment: The normal_behaviour clause does not allow any exceptions as default. "The normal behavior gets an additional clause signals (Throwable t) false" 8.2 of the Key Deductive Software Verification book (2016). I don't see how this method can be passed by the verifier, it will always throw a NullPointerException. Requires has no effect as its set to true and therefore any pre state is allowed.